# Generics - Type mismatch when providing a concrete type to a generic class

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, type-mismatch

Simple Java generics question: I have two classes - one of which uses generics to define its type, the other which extends this class providing a concrete type.

```
public class Box<Item> {
    ...
}


public class Toolbox extends Box<Tool>{
    ...
}
```

Given that Toolbox extends Box providing a Tool as the actual type for the generic placeholder, I would have thought it should be possible to do something like this:

```
Box<Tool> box = new Box();

Toolbox toolbox = box;
```

However, it seems this causes a type-mismatch. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Box<Item>` is the unbound generic type.  `Box<Tool>` is a particular bound version of that same generic type.  `Toolbox` is a subclass of `Box<Tool>` and thus is a discrete type from `Box<Tool>`.

Answer (score 6):

It's not really a generics issue. Your problem is that you're assigning an object of a less specific type to a variable of a more specific type.

You'd have the same problem if you tried to assign an Object to a String variable, even though String extends Object.

You should, however, be able to write `Box<Tool> box = new Toolbox();` with the class structure given. Just not the other way around.

Comment: Of course. Cheers... having a bit of a blonde moment today ;)